# How should you handle errors in a production environment?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I've been following along with some tutorials and have built an app that I'd like to publish, but I'm unsure how to deal with error handling.

Tutorials teach you about things like do-catch blocks but whenever they deal with the case where an error is thrown, they just log the error to console, which is obviously unhelpful in a production environment.

Moreover, some examples of the do-catch blocks appear to have little use. As an example, I'm using Realm Database as a core part of my app, and I'm told the way to initialise it is like so in the AppDelegate:

```
do {
    _ = try Realm()
} catch {
    // TODO: - Handle Exception
}
```

But in this case, since realm is a core part of my app, I wouldn't even mind if it crashed the app, because if it doesn't init properly it's going to crash later anyway.

There are obvious cases when I should just display an error to the user (e.g. If you're trying to connect to an API but there is no wifi), or where a default value could be provided, but I don't know what to do here.

Comment: Unclear what the question is. This is very broad, not to say opinion-based. If you want logging to be useful in a production environment, use `os_log`. If you want to crash if Realm isn't present, say `try!`, or back the whole thing up with a `precondition` call. Also distinguish errors from exceptions; a thrown error is _not_ an exception and an exception is _not_ what is handled in a `catch` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no single good approach to handling errors, since how an error should be handled completely depends on the exact situation.

In general, however, there are some guidelines on error handling:

- Use do-catch blocks on throwable functions unless you have a very
  good reason to do so
- Avoid runtime errors at all costs and don't throw fatal errors. Even if your app encounters an error that cannot be properly handled (the results of a throwable function is absolutely needed for your app to function), don't let your app crash due to a runtime error, rather let the user know that there's something wrong. A crashing application sends a very bad message to your users, while failing gracefully after encountering an error doesn't seem as bad.
- In a catch block, try to solve the error without
  letting the user know that there was an error if the error is
  recoverable (for instance, you can use a default value instead of the
  value you expected from the throwable function)
- If the error can't be
  handled, let the user know that there was an error (such as they
  don't have internet connection when making a network request or a
  network request failed for any other reason) and try to give them an
  alternative approach (i.e. try later when you have internet
  connection)
- Only use `try!` and similar forced methods (force unwrapping, etc.) if you are absolutely sure that the function won't actually throw an error (for instance `Realm.init()` can only throw an error on the very first call to it in an app's lifecycle, so after the first instantiation of `Realm`, you can safely do `try! Realm()`) or if the error represent a programmer error (such as a file not being in the right place, which is needed for the application), but make sure you actually correct such errors in the development phase